# The Film, Student, State, and Time

Tags: logical-deduction

Four students entered their movie in a national student film festival. Using only the clues that follow, determine for each film the director, title, running time, and state in which each was produced (one of which is Pennsylvania). The shortest film was 15 minutes long, and the longest ran 30 minutes.

1. Harvest Sun is shorter than Keith's film.
2. The director of the 20 minute film, Ben, and Gus are three different people.
3. Of the director of Arctic Visions and the one with 25-minute film, one filmed in New York and the other is Eric's.
4. The 20 minute film was made either in Colorado for New York.
5. Gus's film is five minutes shorter then the film in Florida.
6. Dreams Of July is longer than the film in New York.
7. Gus didn't produce Unraveling

Comment: Is this your own puzzle, or does it come from somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

By reading all the clues, we know that :

```
directors = { Keith ; Ben ; Gus ; Eric }  
titles    = { Harvest Sun ; Artic Vision ; Dreams of July ; Unraveling }  
times     = { 15min ; 20min ; 25min ; 30min }  
states    = { Pennsylvania ; New York ; Colorado ; Florida }
```

Since clue 5 is time related, let's start with this configuration :

```
director = { ?     ; ?     ; ?     ; ?     }  
title    = { ?     ; ?     ; ?     ; ?     }  
time     = { 15min ; 20min ; 25min ; 30min }  
state    = { ?     ; ?     ; ?     ; ?     }
```

Clue 2 : Neither Ben and Gus is the 20min film director, so it's either Keith or Eric.
Clue 4 : The state of the 20min film is either Colorado or New York.

```
director = { ?     ; K / E ; ?     ; ?     }
title    = { ?     ; ?     ; ?     ; ?     }
time     = { 15min ; 20min ; 25min ; 30min }
state    = { ?     ; C / N ; ?     ; ?     }
```

Clue 5 : Gus's film is 5min shorter than the Florida's Film wich is only possible with this configuration :

```
director = { ?     ; K / E ; Gus   ; ?       }
title    = { ?     ; ?     ; ?     ; ?       }
time     = { 15min ; 20min ; 25min ; 30min   }
state    = { ?     ; C / N ; ?     ; Florida }
```

Clue 3 : The 25min film is directed by Eric or has been shot in New-York. Only the second option is valid, which leads us to :

```
director = { ?     ; K / E ; Gus      ; ?       }
title    = { ?     ; ?     ; ?        ; ?       }
time     = { 15min ; 20min ; 25min    ; 30min   }
state    = { ?     ; C / N ; New-York ; Florida }
```

By deduction, the states are known :

```
director = { ?            ; K / E    ; Gus      ; ?       }
title    = { ?            ; ?        ; ?        ; ?       }
time     = { 15min        ; 20min    ; 25min    ; 30min   }
state    = { Pennsylvania ; Colorado ; New-York ; Florida }
```

Clue 6 : Dreams of July is longer than the New York film :

```
director = { ?            ; K / E    ; Gus      ; ?              }
title    = { ?            ; ?        ; ?        ; Dreams of July }
time     = { 15min        ; 20min    ; 25min    ; 30min          }
state    = { Pennsylvania ; Colorado ; New-York ; Florida        }
```

Here is the tricky part :
Clue 7 : Unraveling is not Gus's film. --> only the first two availables.
Clue 3 : Artic Vision is Eric's film. --> only the first two availables.

```
director = { ?            ; K / E    ; Gus      ; ?              }
title    = { Un / Ar      ; Un / Ar  ; ?        ; Dreams of July }
time     = { 15min        ; 20min    ; 25min    ; 30min          }
state    = { Pennsylvania ; Colorado ; New-York ; Florida        }
```

So Harvest Sun is found, and with :
Clue 1 : Keith's film is longer than Harvest Sun, here we are :

```
director = { ?            ; K / E    ; Gus         ; Keith          }
title    = { Un / Ar      ; Un / Ar  ; Harvest Sun ; Dreams of July }
time     = { 15min        ; 20min    ; 25min       ; 30min          }
state    = { Pennsylvania ; Colorado ; New-York    ; Florida        }
```

Since Keith is placed, by deduction and with clue 3 again :

```
director = { ?            ; Eric         ; Gus         ; Keith          }
title    = { Un / Ar      ; Artic Vision ; Harvest Sun ; Dreams of July }
time     = { 15min        ; 20min        ; 25min       ; 30min          }
state    = { Pennsylvania ; Colorado     ; New-York    ; Florida        }
```

Finally :

```
director = { Ben          ; Eric         ; Gus         ; Keith          }
title    = { Unraveling   ; Artic Vision ; Harvest Sun ; Dreams of July }
time     = { 15min        ; 20min        ; 25min       ; 30min          }
state    = { Pennsylvania ; Colorado     ; New-York    ; Florida        }
```

Comment: How can I use the spoiler tag >! and the four spaces together without losing the monospaced font ?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. I also think that this is probably the link - https://www.logic-puzzles.org/ - but I do not know which puzzle it is.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

> [Ben, Unraveling, 15-minutes, Pennsylvania],
>  [Eric, Arctic Visions, 20-minutes, Colorado],
>  [Gus, Harvest Sun, 25-minutes, New York],
>  [Keith, Dreams of July, 30-minutes, Florida]

How I solved this:

Will edit this in when I have some time